# Is there a need to use an article in a headline?

Tags: grammaticality, articles, numbers, headline-english

Which should I use?

1. Top restaurants within 5 minute walk
2. Top restaurants within a 5 minute walk

For broader context, this is to be used as a section heading in an app, and so adding an article actually complicates the code, since it now requires the coder to programmatically distinguish between *a* and *an* based on the number falling between *within* and *minute*, since numbers beginning with *one, eight-,* or *eleven* would need the longer article.

Comment: Since you're using headlinese, 'need' becomes hard to define. I'd say the inclusion of the article improves how it sounds, but doesn't increase clarity.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, thanks for the reply. To be more precise, would it be grammatically incorrect to omit an article, or is this a matter of taste/style/sound?

Comment: It's best to say 'grammaticality doesn't really apply to labels, headlines etc'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Actually, headlinese is a serious area of study among linguistics, with [many scholarly papers](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?as_vis=1&q=headlinese&hl=en&as_sdt=0,39) examining its usage. Headlinese has different grammar rules, but it is not true to say it has no grammar rules at all.

Comment: If you bother to search here, there are easily a dozen questions about headlinese, many with excellent answers.

Comment: #2 sounds more natural. Also if it were "8 mile walk" it should be "an" instead of "a".

Comment: Instead of worrying about articles, you could change sentence №1 to _Top restaurants within 5 minutes' walk_ which makes more sense.

Comment: @Laurel Taking the more restrictive definition allowed by ODO: 'the whole system and structure of a language or of languages in general' and choosing standard English, I'm happy with the statement.

Answer (score -2):

I don't have the reputation to comment, but I wanted to add that the article is  actually quite easy to determine programmatically. Use a small library to convert the duration to English (e.g. for Ruby, use [Humanize](https://github.com/radar/humanize)) then prefix "an" if it begins with a vowel, or "a" for a consonant.

Regarding the actual question, I don't honestly think it matters. Just so long as you do that consistently across all headings in your app.